# Trigger based on linked table

Tags: mysql, trigger

OK I have 3 tables:

**client:**

`ClientID` *(int)auto-inc*

`clientName` *(varchar)*

**tnt_group:**

`groupID` *(int)auto-inc*

`ClientID` *(int)foreign-key*

**tnt_item:**

`itemID` *(int)auto-inc*

`itemNo` *(int)*

`groupID` *(int)foreign-key*

Now, I need to generate an `itemNo` for each record in **tnt_item**, starting from 1 for each `ClientID` so each client see's their item count starting from 1. I have tried adding a trigger as follows:

```
BEGIN
    SET NEW.itemNo = (
        SELECT IF(t.itemNo IS NULL, 1, IFNULL(MAX(t.itemNo), 0) + 1)
        FROM (
            SELECT IFNULL(i.itemNo, 0) AS itemNo, g.groupID, g.ClientID, cg.ClientID AS cgClient, cg.groupID  AS cgGroup
            FROM tnt_group cg
            INNER JOIN tnt_group g ON cg.ClientID = g.ClientID
            INNER JOIN tnt_item i ON i.groupID = g.groupID
        ) AS t WHERE t.cgGroup = NEW.groupID
        GROUP BY cgClient
    );
END
```

This is working, in the case where a client already has at least 1 asset, it gets the max `itemNo` then adds one. where it is failing, is if a client does not have any items yet, no matter what I do, it sets the first `itemNo` as `NULL`

Any tips on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: holes in number allowed, items are only ever soft deleted anyway (deleted column)

Comment: I would rather have a stored Id, not rely on an records not being deleted or a function that could change over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr
BEFORE INSERT
ON tnt_item
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.itemNo = 1 + COALESCE((SELECT MAX(t1.itemNo)
                               FROM tnt_item t1, tnt_group t2, tnt_group t3
                               WHERE t1.groupID = t2.groupID
                                 AND t2.ClientID = t3.ClientID
                                 AND t3.groupID = NEW.groupID), 0);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e3a5fd47eb9560737974e11a8a86bb4)

Comment: That looks like it will do what I'm after. I can't try yet, will be back at my desk in a couple of hours and will try then. Thanks for your time.